# Can't enable Compiz Plugins ~

Tags: compiz, fglrx

I have a Radeon 290 graphics card - and I'm using the `fglrx-updates` for the driver on 14.10 - with the default, 3.16 kernel. I originally thought that the graphics driver was the problem, but that doesn't seem to be the case - especially since -  according to [the compiz wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/Troubleshooting#ATI_Cards) - the fglrx drivers are compatible -

When I open CompizConfig settings manager, I cannot enable or disable ***any*** of the plugins, although the default ones are already enabled.

I appreciate any insight anyone can give on this problem.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver - helpful?

Comment: Haha, somewhat! It seems that my chip is not listed as supported, so I have to wonder if that page is just outdated or if my chip really isn't supported... When I went to install the drivers under "Additional Drivers" - the fglrx was the only one that showed up, aside from the default driver, which did not allow for transparency - hmm...